# Not able to execute a jar file using php exec, though it works in the terminal

Tags: java, php, jar, exec

I have a jar file I need to call from `PHP`, Jar is running good when I directly hit it from terminal like this

```
java -cp vajavastlib.jar:. GetVirtualCard
```

I am using `ubuntu 15.04`. But when I call it in a controller (using yii framework) like this

`exec("java -cp vajavastlib.jar:. GetVirtualCard");`

its returning empty string.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Did you try with a second argument: `exec(...., $output); echo  $output;` ?

Comment: yeah but still same result

Comment: Do you know for sure the *jar* is executed or not? Could you try with providing the complete path to *java*?

Comment: I tried with full path with no success :(

Comment: Do you know for sure the *jar* is executed or not?

Comment: No I am not sure is there any way to find it out, but its working from terminal

Comment: Could you do this: `exec("java -cp vajavastlib.jar:. GetVirtualCard", $output, $status); ` and see what *$status* is? If non-zero, it means there was an error. If so, please try the same with the full path of *java*. If still non-zero, what is the value?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are not able to see the output or any error. The output is not going to the php handler. Add 2>&1 in your command at the end.
It will definitely show the output.
Also, make sure the jar file is in a public directory.